# Why can't i log out by sending a post request using reactjs even if my django backend for logout is working well

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
class LogoutView(APIView):
  def post(self, request):
    try:
        token = Token.objects.get(user=request.user)
        Token.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete()

        if token:
            return Response({'detail': 'Succesifully logged out'}, 
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'detail': 'No token found for this user'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    except Exception as e:
        return Response({'detail': 'Failed to logout'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**This is my frontend code for logout **

```
const handleSignOut = async () => {
    

    try {
        // localStorage.removeItem('token')
        // window.location.reload()
        
        
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/logout/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        
        },

        body: JSON.stringify({}),
      });

     
      console.log("Request Headers:", JSON.stringify(response.headers));

      if (response.ok) {
          console.log("logout  succesifull");
          localStorage.removeItem('token')
        
      } else {
        console.log("Logout failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("An error occured while trying to logout", error);
    }
  };
```

I triend to send post request using reactjs for logout, but it resulted to bad request on the django rest backend, but when i use django rest interface to logout, its working perfectly